# Subnet masks to separate out modem LAN (10.0.0.*) from the internet for OpenVPN

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

Im trying to run all requests to "the internet" through the VPN EXCEPT for my LAN requests.

I THINK I need two rules for openVPN to separate out:

1. Local traffic anything from 10.0.0.0 to 10.0.0.255.
2. Everything else.

I've verified that all my local network machines all have 10.0.0.* addresses -- and I want those to communicate directly, NOT through the VPN

And then everything else thats NOT on the 10.0.0.* subnet gets run through the VPN.

Comment: Where are you setting this VPN info? Each machine can only have 1 IP address (unless you have dual ports) so they will all be part of the 10.0.0.0 network so I'm not sure what you mean by everything else not part of it should go to the VPN.

Comment: Restated: If the IP being requested is not between 10.0.0.0 and 10.0.0.255  ... route that request through the VPN

Comment: Does this help? https://superuser.com/questions/610601/openvpn-route-all-traffic-except-select-local-subnets